# Does calling Abort on HttpWebRequest has any affect on responseStream.BeginRead

Tags: c#, .net

From MSDN:

> "The Abort method cancels a request to a resource. After a request is
>   canceled, calling the GetResponse, BeginGetResponse, EndGetResponse,
>   GetRequestStream, BeginGetRequestStream, or EndGetRequestStream method
>   causes a WebException with the Status property set to
>   RequestCanceled."

But if `responseStream.BeginRead` is in progress, does `Abort` cancel this read?

Comment: First, try it and see if it affects the BeginRead.  If it does, then you know the answer.  If it seems to not affect it, then your question still stands.

Comment: MSDN sample includes ReadCallBack processing, so it looks like it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is affecting reading from a stream. I have tested sample code that was used in msdn [HttpWebRequest.Abort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx#Y500), and call to `EndRead` was throwing an exception in `ReadCallBack` function.

```
RequestState myRequestState = (RequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
Stream responseStream = myRequestState.streamResponse;
int read = responseStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
```

> ReadCallBack Exception raised!
>
> Message:The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
>
> Status:RequestCanceled Press any key to continue..........